# What is a valid eventId in EventStore?

Tags: eventstoredb

When I try to post an event without an eventId, I get:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Empty eventId provided.

If I populate eventId with something random, then I get:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Write request body invalid

In the stdout of the server, I see:

> Error converting value "foo" to type 'System.Guid'

What does it take to get a valid EventId?

command:

```
curl -i -d @event.json localhost:2113/streams/birthday-offer \
     -H "Content-Type:application/vnd.eventstore.events+json"
```

event.json:

```
[
  {
     "eventId": "foo",
     "eventType": "bar",
     "data": { 
       "who": "11111111111",
       "which": "birthday-offer"
     }  
  } 
]
```

I'm not in a .NET language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just in case anyone else comes across this question, the answer is EventId is a Guid.

According to [the docs](http://docs.geteventstore.com/http-api/3.0.1/writing-to-a-stream/), you can even omit the EventId and the server will provide the Id for you.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://docs.geteventstore.com/http-api/3.0.3/writing-to-a-stream/) you can omit the EventId header if it's preferable or necessary for the server to generate the id for you.  When you do that the server will redirect you to a location indicated by the generated event identifier, which you can then post event data to.  I haven't gotten this to work myself though ...